# Adding validation to observableArray items with knockout.validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, knockout.js

I'm trying to validat the fields in the following form structure with knockout.validation.

```
form body:
  static fields (observables) 
  field_container:(observableArray)
     n dynamic fields (observables)
```

Here's a simple implementation at jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ltg/4/
I can validate the static fields upon calling errors.showAllMessages, but dynamic fields are not validated. How can i validate the observables in observableArray?

Edit: RTFM: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration
Adding grouping : {deep: true} to configuration makes all the nested structures validatable too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution i found is to walk through the observablearray elements, validating each one manually.  I've modified the jsfiddle code accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ltg/7/